# How to apply position_dodge to geom_point and geom_text in the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I woul like to be able to make the geom_text inside the geom_point to follow the re-positioning when applying position_dodge. That is, I would like to go from the code below:

```
Q <- as_tibble(data.frame(series = rep(c("diax","diay"),3),
                          value = c(3.25,3.30,3.31,3.36,3.38,3.42),
                          year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2020,2020))) %>%
  select(year, series, value)

ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = series, label = sprintf("%.2f",value))) +
  geom_point(size = 13) +
  geom_text(vjust = 0.4,color = "white", size = 4, fontface = "bold", show.legend = FALSE)
```

which produces the following chart:

[image]

to the following change:

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = series, label = sprintf("%.2f",value))) +
  geom_point(size = 13, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0.4,
            color = "white", size = 4, fontface = "bold",
            show.legend = FALSE)
```

which produces the following chart:

[image]

The curious thing about this is the fact that excatly the same change works just fine if I change from geom_point to geom_bar:

```
ggplot(Q, aes(year, value, fill = factor(series), label = sprintf("%.2f",value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
  geom_text(color = "black", size = 4,fontface= "bold",
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0.4, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the the dodging is based on the `group` aesthetic, automatically set in this case to `series` because of the mapping to color. The issue is that the text layer has it's own color (`"white"`) and so the grouping is dropped. Manually set the grouping, and all is good:

```
ggplot(Q, aes(x = year, y = value, color = series, label = sprintf("%.2f",value), group = series)) +
    geom_point(size = 13, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0.4, color = "white", size = 4, 
              fontface = "bold", show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One patch work would be the following. Since you cannot add labels on top of the data point using `geom_text()` right away, you may want to go round a bit. I first created a temporary graphic with `geom_point()`. Then, I accessed to the data frame which is used for drawing the graphic. You can find the values of x and y axis. Using them, I created a new data frame called `temp` which include the axis information and the label information. Once I had this data frame, I could draw the expected outcome using `temp`. Make sure that you use `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_text()` since you are using another data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(data = Q, aes(x = year, y = value, color = series)) +
     geom_point(size = 13, position = position_dodge(width = 1))

temp <- as.data.frame(ggplot_build(g)$data) %>%
        select(x, y) %>%
        arrange(x) %>%
        mutate(label = sprintf("%.2f",Q$value))

ggplot(data = Q, aes(x = year, y = value, color = series)) +
geom_point(size = 13, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
geom_text(data = temp, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), 
          color = "white", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]